# How to address lots of buttons in vb.net in shortest code

Tags: vb.net, button, short

I am making a TicTacToe Program in Vb.net and it is essentially 9 games into one "big" game. So I have 81 buttons I want to disable able the winner is determined. How can I address them all in the shortest amount of code?

```
Private Sub CheckOverallWinner()
If humangame1 = 1 And humangame2 = 1 And humangame3 = 1 Then
MsgBox("Human Wins")
Button1.Enabled = False
Button2.Enabled = False
Button3.Enabled = False
Button4.Enabled = False
Button5.Enabled = False
Button6.Enabled = False
Button7.Enabled = False
Button8.Enabled = False
Button9.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

So instead of writing Button_.Enabled = False all the way through 81 is there a shorter way? Thanks!

Comment: Add them in a list and loop through the list.

Comment: 81 buttons? I think you might need to reconsider your logic. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim o As Object
    For Each o In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf o Is Button Then
            o.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

Just tried this in VS2008

Answer (score 0):

Another option using Controls.Find().  This will work no matter where the buttons are contained, even if they are in multiple containers:

```
Private Sub Foo()
    SetButtonsState(False)
End Sub

Private Sub SetButtonsState(ByVal state As Boolean)
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 81
        matches = Me.Controls.Find("Button" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Button Then
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(matches(0), Button)
            btn.Enabled = state
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```